# Issue in iterating the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array named `a[]` which contains the `city_id` and city name

Then I am doing edit and i get the details such as `cityID`,`countryid`,etc

and save it in `var b= cityID`

Now to get the `cityname` and appending to the field `textbox`

i am iterating the array a thru each function

```
 function f1() {
     jQuery(a). each(function(m) {
         if(this.city_id(from array a) == cityID)
             if(c== "") {
                 c += this.cityname;
             } else {
                 c += ","+ this.cityname;
             }
     }); 
 }
```

`c` is a global `var` the problem is on click of edit i get `c` as say `Bombay`,`Delhi`,`Puna`

but again next time if i click on another radio button to fetch that details it gets appended to `Bombay`,`Delhi`,`Puna`,`Chennai` like this instead of clearing the first one.

Comment: did you try to re-set your `c` direct after calling `f1()`?
`function f1() { c=""; //... 
}`

Comment: `this.city_id(from array a)` isn't JavaScript.

Comment: c is a global variable which is var c=""; where to reset it

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `c` to an empty string at the beginning of the function:

```
function f1() {
    c = '';
    $(a).each(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global variable `c` you can make `c` a local variable and return it at end of your `function`.

```
function f1() {
  var c ='';
  jQuery(a). each(function(m) {
     if(this.city_id(from array a) == cityID)
         if(c== "") {
             c += this.cityname;
         } else {
             c += ","+ this.cityname;
         }
  }); 
  return c;
}
```

Comment: so what is c in the beginnng is it an empty string as u gave only var c;

Comment: In javascript you don't need to define type of the variable, it will automatically defined when you set value into it.

Comment: because only if c is empty string only then that if condition will work

Comment: if(c== "") {
             c += this.cityname;
         } else {
             c += ","+ this.cityname;
         }

Answer (score 0):

try this..
Here i each obj in an array.

```
$.each( a, function( i, val ) {
  if(i.city_id== cityID)
             if(c== "") {
                 c += this.cityname;
             } else {
                 c += ","+ this.cityname;
             }
});
```